# Filtering a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array with shape (2,50,000) - which means I have 50k samples of x,y values.

I want to filter the x,y values within a certain range, lets say:

```
min < x,y < max
```

I tried using `np.apply_along_axis` with a filter function, but I couldn't make it work.

I'd love to get to see some pythonic way of executing this simple task!

Comment: Do you mean selecting only the values for which this is True? then (assuming no special things occur) you'd have to flatten the array and use `arr[np.logical_and(_min <= arr, arr <= _max)]` or something.
If you instead meant simple clipping then use [`np.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

Comment: @RotemShalev Thanks, I didn't mean clipping, I truely want to select the values for which is it true. What do you mean by flattening the array?

Comment: I accidentally read your array shape as 3D, sorry. Please ignore that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your array being `arr` and your values being `(_min, _max)`, use:

```
selection = np.logical_and(_min <= arr, arr <= _max)
selection = np.logical_and(selection[0], selection[1])
filtered_arr = arr[:, selection]
```

Comment: Thanks alot!
What if I had a 3D array with x,y,z values, and I wanted to take only the x,y,z values, where  min < z < max (filter by z)

Comment: Would this work?

`selection = np.logical_and(_min <= arr[2], arr <= _max[2])
filtered_arr = arr[:, selection]`